# Unable to fit model using “orm.fit” from package "rms"

Tags: r, regression, anova, rms

I want to compare species richness from different sample types collected from different stations.
Below is a subset of my data:

```
test_df <- structure(list(S = c(362.37, 436.53, 403.37, 433.49, 432.16, 
            461.46, 524.18, 505.76, 461.51, 420.87, 445.61, 436.1, 450.67, 
            396.92, 516.73, 687.81, 670.48, 672.9, 548.41, NA, 519.19, 470.82, 
            495.18, 418.94, 266.01, 309.44, 237.79, 489.67, 449.1, 501.02, 
            440.11, 436.94, 447.69, 358.1, 359.2, 342.93, 240.52, 247.03, 
            238.44, 361.58, 356.16, 332.73, 368.66, 413.56, 479.05, 303.69, 
            256.26, 214.3, 372.16, 360.99, 371.26, 658.53, 620.77, 630.39, 
            550.42, 540.52, 557.64, 439.5, 461.07, 417.21), station = structure(c(4L, 
            4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
            2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
            1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
            4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("MP11", 
            "MP3", "MP9", "TF0046"), class = "factor"), sample_type = structure(c(1L, 
            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
            3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
            5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("st1", 
            "st2", "st3", "st4", "st5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("S", 
            "station", "sample_type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("X007", 
            "X008", "X009", "X023", "X024", "X025", "X051", "X052", "X053", 
            "X060", "X061", "X062", "X118", "X119", "X120", "X134", "X135", 
            "X136", "X162", "X163", "X164", "X171", "X172", "X173", "X223", 
            "X224", "X225", "X226", "X227", "X228", "X232", "X233", "X234", 
            "X235", "X236", "X237", "X250", "X251", "X252", "X253", "X254", 
            "X255", "X259", "X260", "X261", "X262", "X263", "X264", "X277", 
            "X278", "X279", "X280", "X281", "X282", "X286", "X287", "X288", 
            "X289", "X290", "X291"))
```

Because the residuals of my data are not normally distributed and the variances are not homogenous 
(also not after transformation) I was looking for non-parametric alternatives and found that an 
ordinal regression model would probably fit. 
However, when I run the model including the interaction term "sample_type * station" using the orm-function
from package rms, I get an error message and several warnings.
(I am using R version 3.4.2 on an Windows machine and package "rms" version 5.1-2)

```
orm_test <- orm(S ~ sample_type * station, data = test_df)
```

Which gives me this:

```
Did not converge in 12 iterations
Unable to fit model using  “orm.fit” 
Warning messages:
1: In ormfit(x, y, kint, nx, initial = initial, offset = offset, penmat = penmat,  :
cell probability < 1e-10 in iteration 3, set to 1e-10
(warning is repeated 10X)
```

I figured that this might be due to a very small sample size when the interaction term is included 
(only 3 observations per sample type and per station), because when I run the model with "S ~ sample_type + station" it works.

However, I am not sure if my assumption is correct and I simply cannot use an ordinal regression model due to my 
limited sample size or if I am using the model incorrectly!

Any help for clarification on that would be greatly appreciated!
(I could not find anything regarding my warning messages in connection with function “orm”).